# Excel VBA Attempting to set cell value as date from another cell

Tags: excel, vba, date-format

I have a spreadsheet where our organisation is required to submit sickness information on a weekly basis for staff. The spreadsheet has one tab for each week of the year and I already have a macro to copy employee details from one week to the next.

I'm attempting to build in the code below where it picks up staff who are still on sick leave and copies the start date of the sickness period to the following week. The code works by picking up an employee number as a string in the loop, then creating an object for the start date.

Due to the layout and other information on the templates I can't simply copy and paste the whole sheet from one week to the next.

**REVISED**
The revised code below now copies the first `SicknessStart` date to `NextWeek`. However it only works on the first date and won't copy the information from the subsequent rows for some reason. The date format is also copying accross in US format but I'm looking into that.

```
Sub CopyDate

 Dim I As Integer, CopyDate As Boolean
 I = 6
 CopyDate = False

 'Use the Employee Number column (C) to perform the check on the sickness dates
 Do While CurrentWeek.Cells(I, 3) <> ""

'Check if there is a sickness start date in column R
If CurrentWeek.Cells(I, 18) <> "" Then
'Check if they have entered 'Still Away' or left the cell blank in column S
    If CurrentWeek.Cells(I, 19) = "Still Away" Or CurrentWeek.Cells(I, 19) = "" Then

        Dim EmployeeNumber As String
        Dim SicknessStart As String
            EmployeeNumber = Cells(I, 3)
            SicknessStart = Cells(I, 18)

        NextWeek.Select

'Find the employee number string on the following week's tab and enter sickness start date   
        Columns(3).Find(What:=EmployeeNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 15) = SicknessStart

End If
End If

I = I + 1
Loop
CopySickness = True
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried just copying the value and formatting the cell after that, or not at all?

Comment: To get better help:   
1) You don't tell us what is going wrong  
2) there is no such thing as a "date object"

Comment: @Vogel612 I have tried  to copy the cell and paste it but that doesn't seem to be working at the moment, will keep on trying with that method though. @iDevlop On `CurrentWeek` If I have a date of 01/01/13 as the `StartDate`, it doesn't take that date accross onto `NextWeek`, instead it defaults to 01/00/1900. I didn't phrase the title properly, what I meant was the date is set `StartDate as Date` as opposed to a String or any other variable.

Comment: I have revised the code above which now copies the date correctly but only for the first entry. SicknessStart (which was StartDate) is now a String but that brings the date accross in US format. I tried to use `CDate` but that only works if there one date entry. If there is more than one date then I get a mismatch error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how `CurrentWeek` or `NextWeek` are declared or set. I'll assume they are global `worksheet` variables (a bad idea by the way, they should be parameters passed into this `sub`) that are set elsewhere.

---

Then qualify *all* `cell` references with one or the other.

```
        EmployeeNumber = CurrentWeek.Cells(I, 3)
        SicknessStart = CurrentWeek.Cells(I, 18)
```

---

This line is the cause of your problems (delete it)
Why? Because on the second time through the unqualified `EmployeeNumber = Cells(I, 3)` etc refer to sheet `NextWeek`

```
NextWeek.Select
```

---

`Find`ing the Employee number using a `Range` variable

```
Dim rStartDate as Range

' replace your Columns(3).Find(... code with this
Set rStartDate = NextWeek.Columns(3).Find( _
  What:=EmployeeNumber, _
  LookIn:=xlValues, _
  LookAt:=xlWhole, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
  SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
  MatchCase:=False, _
  SearchFormat:=False)
If Not rStartDate Is Nothing Then
    rStartDate.Offset(0, 15) = SicknessStart
Else
    ' EmployeeNumber is not found in NextWeek.Column(3)
End If
```

Comment: Sorry `CurrentWeek` and `NextWeek` are declared earlier in this `sub` but I didn't include all the code as it wasn't wholly relevant to this issue. I will try using a `range` variable instead and see if that works.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but he couldn't use a range, because he needs to select them entry by entry, nice would be something like "SUMIF()" just as a "COPYIF()" but i guess thats too localized to be in excel, even though i often missed it somehow...

Comment: @chrisneilsen That's worked a treat, thanks for your help. Now all I need to do is work out the US/UK date format! :)

Comment: I amended the code to show `SicknessStart as Date` and then `SicknessStart = CDate(CurrentWeek.Cells(I, 18))` which keeps the date in the UK format that I require. I will revise the description in full later.